# Spring scheduled - can I join fixed delay with cron

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I am using spring and springboot, and I have case with two tasks, which until now was triggered by `@Scheduled` with fixed delay. It is a must condition, that next task won't start if previous did not end. But now I got another requirement, tasks can only be triggered between specific hours and for the rest of the day it must not. I read documentation of `@Scheduled` but I do not see such an option. So my question is, if there is simple solution where:

- task will not start before the previous is not ended
- task will be triggered only between 15:00 and 18:00
  or I have to do some code gimmick for it?

Comment: what is your current schedule? you can always specify the cron expression to run between specific time period

Comment: @sidgate currently I am using ```@Scheduled(fixedDelayString=1000)``` so condition with no overlapping trigger is met but I am trying to find the cleaniest solution to add time boundaries.

But as I undestand spring docu, what you propose wont prevent from triggering task several time

Comment: Use a proper scheduling solution like Quartz or JobRunr for this, don't try to invent your own. `@Scheduled` is meant for the simple cases not for complexer ones.

Comment: Need to try out: Define Single threaded `TaskScheduler` and refer it in `@Scheduler`. Use `@Schedules({ 
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000), 
  @Scheduled(cron = "* * 15-17 * * *")
})`